# What does the below statement mean?

Tags: typescript

**Does it means that the given datatype can store number and Datatype T?**
`type Address<T extends string> = number & { type: T }`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types

Comment: That means `never`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means

Address is an alias for the intersection type of number and the generic type T.

```
type Address<T extends string> = number & { type: T }
```

Intersection means that Address will have all features of both types.